# Log4J Question - Two log infos are printed out for one statement in Eclipse Console Window

Tags: java, log4j

I found the logging information is printed out twice when using logger.info like

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
logger.info("From Log4J sample");
```

The Output is Like

> ```
> From Log4J sample
> 0 [main] INFO com.mycompany.app.App  - From Log4J sample
> ```

My configuration like the following

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
```

Is it expected or something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are configuring Log4j with your configuration properties, which adds a `ConsoleAppender`. Then you are configuring Log4j with `BasicConfigurator`, which adds another `ConsoleAppender`. Each log event is written by both appenders.

Use a configuration file *or* `BasicConfigurator`, not both.